# Put in the shoes of

Tags: phrases

Please guide me on whether the used phrase is right.

I put myself in the shoes of the customer before preparing the requirement.

Thanks & Regards,
Murali.

Comment: You can often find idioms like ["put yourself in someone's shoes"](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/be+in+somebody%27s+shoes#shoe_1__28) in dictionaries with examples of how to use them. For example, look up the main word *shoe* and you can find idioms containing it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is correct, but it would probably have a clearer meaning if you rearranged the order of the sentence

> I put myself in the customer's shoes before preparing the requirement.

as the expression is usually "in [X]'s shoes".

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfectly acceptable use of this idiom.